# CSS class naming convention for media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, naming-conventions, classname, bem

What would be the best classname convention for the following example.

If I have **different** elements with the **same** grid layout.

```
<div class="item__1 -has-multipleColumns-XL">Text</div>
<div class="item__2 -has-multipleColumns-XL">Text</div>
```

and on smaller screen sizes would want to shrink it to two or a single column, would you change the the current class or have separate, overwriting classname for smaller media queries like:

```
<div class="item__1 -has-threeColumns-XL -has-twoColumns-M -has-singleColumns-S">Text</div>
<div class="item__2 -has-threeColumns-XL -has-twoColumns-M -has-singleColumns-S">Text</div>
```

either:

```
//XL screens
.-has-threeColumns-XL {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

//Medium screens
@media (max-width: 50rem) {
  .-has-twoColumns-M {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

// Small screens
@media (max-width: 30rem) {
  .-has-singleColumns-S {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

or:

```
// XL screens
.item__1,
.item__2 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

// Medium screens
@media (max-width: 50rem) {
  .item__1,
  .item__2 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

// Small screens
@media (max-width: 50rem) {
  .item__1,
  .item__2 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

I hope it's clear what I mean

(The combination of BEM and camelcase comes from ATOM.)

Thx!

Comment: Since you're styling the same element, I would omit the xl, m and s naming convention and go with something shorter and more concise like has-columns.

Answer (score 0):

If the texts in the different div elements have a semantic property in common, use that name for the class. Otherwise, just call the class *grid* and use media queries to style it for different screen sizes.